# Selecting an int array from Postgres into struct and then marshalling it

Tags: sql, postgresql, go

I have the following struct:

```
type Payment struct {
    ...
    PaymentMethods []int64 `json:"paymentMethods,omitempty" db:"payment_methods"`
}
```

In Postgres database, I have a simple `[]int` column named `payment_methods` in payments table.

I need to make a simple Select query to get that struct and then marshall it to return it to the REST API in json format.

However, when I run the following:

```
payment := Payment{}
err := psql.db.Unsafe().Get(&payment, "select * from payments where id = $1", id)
```

I get an error :
`sql: Scan error on column index 12, name "payment_methods": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value t`

Now, I know that I can use the `pq.Int64Array` type instead of `[]int`.
However, the marshalling part won't work for that. I want to find a simpler solution that wouldn't add unnecessary overhead (unless it's impossible of course).

The marshalled struct then is encoded in this part:

```
func (handler *Handler) respond(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, data interface{}, status int) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    w.WriteHeader(status)
    if data != nil {
        err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(data)
        if err != nil {
            errors.Wrap(err, "Response Error while encoding data to json")
            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusNotFound), http.StatusNotFound)
        }
    }
}
```

How can I handle it in a generic way?

I'm using sqlx with pgx driver.

Comment: what is the marshalling that does not work ? Can you elaborate your question with assertions coupled with minimal reproducible exampls ? https://play.golang.org/p/5H6qGO0Eokd

Comment: Other than the suggestion from the link, the only thing that comes to mind at the moment is creating a custom type from []int64 and implementing `Scan` for that custom type.
https://www.opsdash.com/blog/postgres-arrays-golang.html

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you meant. I've edited my post, and added the part where the encoding happens for the marshalled struct happens. And the marshalling itself happens when I call `psql.db.Unsafe().Get(&payment, ....`

Comment: okay, you meant the pg to go marshalling, not the json rest api marshaling. It is required that the type you use to marshall the database value from pg to go, when it is a on trivial type, implements the db.Scanner interface described here  https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner So you must declare that payment_methods property with a type that implements the scanner interface, thus, use `pq.Int64Array`. This error occurs because the type `[]int` does not implement the db.Scanner interface.